# Firebase Storage or realtime Database for rarely updated files

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

My app should show static data which updates every two weeks.

For this i want to use the Firebase services. Is it possible to save these "statics" datas in the `Firebase Storage` (save data as an "JSON" file) or should i use the `Realtime Database`?

In my eyes the real time database is to expensive for such a simple operation - there is no need to be "realtime". Or do you think there are better options?

Comment: If you don't have a server of your own which can host your data, then Firebase would be an option to go with. However, if your data updates every two weeks, then personally I think you should use local SQLite database, and sync the data whenever it is updated.

Comment: If you're using the `Realtime Database`, you will save some bandwidth because you won't need to download the full JSON file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend storing this data in either Firebase Storage or Firebase Hosting, as these are good for storing static, binary data that's rarely updated.

The difference between those two is that Firebase Storage can be updated by end users as well as the developer, while Hosting will require you to deploy new static content. Both happen pretty much instantly, but the deployment mechanism is different.

Per our docs, we discuss the differences:

- [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)
- [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-databae/)
- [Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)
- [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

The best place to store your data, depends on the type of data you want to store and the way you want to consume it.

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/#implementation_path) says this about it:

> - The Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON application data, like game state or chat messages, and synchronizes changes instantly across all connected devices.
> - Firebase Remote Config stores developer-specified key-value pairs to change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an update.
> - Firebase Hosting hosts the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for your website as well as other developer-provided assets like graphics, fonts, and icons.
> - Firebase Storage stores files such as images, videos, and audio as well as other user-generated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase without realtime functionality and load data only once when activity is opened. Just call `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` on firebase instance:

```
firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

To work on realtime call `.addValueEventListener()`.